# How to pass text dynamically in xpath under Properties file

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, xpath, properties-file

I am stuck in a situation where I want to write Xpath dynamically in the properties file. The actual XPath is like in property File `div[contains(text(),'<state Name>')]`. State Name changes everytime. How can I write dynamic xpath which fetches from property file?

below is Xpath stored in properties file

```
data=div[contains(text(),'New Delhi')]
```

and below code snippet is fetching xpath in  test script

```
String checkCity=prop.getProperty(data) ; 
WebElement xpath = driver.findElement(By.xpath(prop.getProperty(locatorKey)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the String [*replace* method](https://www.w3schools.com/java/ref_string_replace.asp).

```
String city            = prop.getProperty("data"); // New Delhi
String locatorTemplate = prop.getProperty("locatorKey"); // div[contains(text(),'<state Name>')]
String locator         = locatorTemplate.replace(locatorPattern, city); // div[contains(text(),'New Delhi')]
WebElement element     = driver.findElement(locator);
```

*locatorPattern* in your case would be *<state Name>*.

The method syntax is as follows:

```
public String replace(char searchChar, char newChar)
```

Answer (score 1):

You create a string

```
String cityName = "London";
String data = "div[contains(text(),"+ "'"+cityName +"'"+")]";
System.out.println(data);
```

You can put in a for loop and then use this data value as locator.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to skip the reading from properties file part, since you seem to have figured it out.

Let's say you have

```
String data = "div[contains(text(),'New Delhi')]";
```

You can use Java's split() method to split that string with `'` as the delimiter:

```
a.split("'")
```

And then take the second element of the resulting array:

```
a.split("'")[1]
```

So

```
System.out.println(a.split("'")[1]);
```

will print out "New Delhi" to console.